How to style showcmdloc=last?
How can I change styling/colorscheme for the region that shows the command being typed, if I have:
set showcmd
" show typed in command in the last screen line:
set showcmdloc=last


The region can be seen above. I am typing "10" to input 10 repetitions of a command in command mode, on the last line,.

Do you still have something open in your question? How can we help you further? Otherwise maybe could you accept one of the solutions using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allow the question to rest :-)

@VivianDeSmedt thanks for the attention. i did not return here for the last couple days and missed your answer then

In general to know what are the highlighting group that can be used to control the aspect of the user interface you can use the :help highlight-groups
key command
I believe there is no solution yet for this area of the screen.
The current key command color is controlled via the Normal highlighting group but it is the same group that controls the standard text character and many more.
command
The Vim command color is controlled via the MsgArea highlighting group.
More information with  :help hl-MsgArea
e.g.: In order to have your command in green you could have:
:highlight MsgArea guifg=#008000

Remark: Thanks to @RomainL this highlighting group is only available for Vim version after version 9.1.0277 (version 9.1 including patches 1-277).

You should mention that this highlight group is pretty recent. As of today, not everyone has 9.1.0277 or later.

MsgArea added color the command input region, not the region that displays the command-mode commands. I've added a screen shot to make it clear. You can see it shows in default colors on top of the msgArea.

i'm not very hopeful as the help for highlight doesn't have any mention of 'showcmd' :(

Thanks for the feedback and the screenshot. I understand you want to change the color of the key buffer. I'm not it exist yet but I'll cross check :-)

There is no highlight group for that area. Note that it integrates well with the statusline and tablinefill highlight groups if you play with :h 'showcmdloc', but not with msgarea, which looks like an oversight to me. OP should open an issue, IMO.
